# How to design an Info-Screen filled with detailed informations about an object

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How can I redesign this infoscreen from an Android Food Deliver App in an efficient and clean way? (especially the "ALLGEMEINE INFO" part)

[image: Infoscreen (Goal)]

Currently I am doing it with a ScrollView, filled with a Main LinearLayout (orientation=vertical). Within are more interleaved Linearlayouts, which make the whole thing complex and not clean.

Here my current Code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Restaurant"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar.MaterialRatingBar
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialRatingBar.RatingBar.Indicator.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/restaurant_item_num_ratings"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restaurant_item_num_ratings"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="32 Bewertungen"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ALLGEMEINE INFO"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="11:00 - 23:00"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Öffnungszeiten" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some Restaurant"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Firmenname" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the Design Preview of it:

[image: My current design (preview)]

Is there a "cleaner" way to design it? With a RecyclerView, etc., or somthing else?
Btw, the individual elements will be loaded from a Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RecyclerView and objects to fill it instead fixed LinearLayout

Some data could be absent, so you will get empty rows....

Answer (score 0):

As Artem stated a Recyclerview would be beneficial here. Also I would suggest placing info within Cardviews depending on how you want the info displayed you can make some really clean looking info/details layouts. If you do it right the recyclerview will be much more appetizing than the scroll view.